# Problemas ao acessar API externa C#

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou tentando acessar a API do PagSeguro para visualizar o saldo da conta mas aparece o seguinte erro. (Apaguei o meu email e token no print assim como no código abaixo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Print da documentação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código na controladora:

```
string url = String.Format("https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/transfer/balance?email=&token=");

            //Classe que irá fazer a requisição GET.
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

            //Método do webrequest.
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/vnd.pagseguro.com.br.v1+json";
            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;


            //Obtém resposta do servidor.
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                //Cria stream para obter retorno.
                using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    //Lê stream.
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            return View();
```

Comment: se suas credenciais estão corretas, pode ser um problema de valdação do ssl. Tente acrescentar essa linha após criar o `Request`:  `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);`

Comment: ja tentou via postman?

Comment: via postman ainda não, farei os testes e dou o feedback, muito obrigado pela ajuda.